# How to configure mutt to set From: header to the value of the original message To: header when replying?

Tags: email, mutt

I use a different email address for each service I sign up for, for example `jj+uber@example.com` or `netflix@jj.example.com` (thanks to Fastmail's [subdomain addressing](https://www.fastmail.com/help/receive/addressing.html)). Mail to all these addresses arrives in the same inbox.

When replying, I would like Mutt to automatically set the `From:` header to the address the original email was sent to. I have tried setting `reverse_name = yes` according to [the documentation](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#reverse-name) but this requires me to specify all the possible `From:` addresses in advance as "alternates":

> If this variable is set, the default From: line of the reply messages is built using the address where you received the messages you are replying to if that address matches your “alternates”.

Currently, I press `Esc` `F` to edit the from address manually for every email I reply to. How can I set the `From:` address of my replies automatically?

Answer (score 3):

The following configuration achieves this:

```
set reverse_name = yes
alternates = @example.com @jj.example.com
```

This works because the `alternates` [are interpreted as regular expressions](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#alternates). The first expression matches `jj+ANYTHING@example.com` and the second one matches `ANYTHING@jj.example.com`.

Using this configuration, when you reply to any email, the `From:` address will be automatically set to the `To:` address of the original email.